# Windows 7 removes boot camp drivers on reboot

Tags: windows-7, drivers, boot-camp

I'm installing boot camp on 64 bit windows 7 home premium from a leopard disc. During installation I get a couple of errors saying that some driver publishers are not registered or something and I install them anyway. After reboot windows tries to repair something and reboots again. When I finally log in, there is no boot camp any more. Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks

btw, I'm using Macbook Pro 15 inch Santa Rosa (late 2007)

Comment: You are using Windows 7 x64 or Server 2008 R2? Server 2008 R2 requires drivers to be signed, so I would think that they will not install.

Comment: I'm using windows 7 x64 home premium. Is there a workaround to bypass signature checks?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having the same problem, here is what I did. Although, keyboard functional keys are not working, I was able to install trackpad drivers. I used Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider.